# Convert timestamp to date results in time out of range error

Tags: linux, bash, date, timestamp, iso8601

I`m trying to convert a timestamp to an ISO8601 datetime-string.

E.g.

```sh
timestamp_as_iso8601_date=$(date --iso-8601=ns -d @1606982602015489365)
```

The timestamp is fairly long, with nanoseconds precision, and when I use the full timestamp it returns the following error:
`date: time ‘1606982602015489365’ is out of range`

The expected result should be: `2020-12-03T09:03:22,015489300+01:00`

When I cut the timestamp to this: `1606982612` the error is gone but I loose information!

Is there any way to convert the timestamp without losing the milliseconds information?

Comment: `The expected result should be: 2020-12-03T09:03:32,000000000+01:00` ... `without losing the milliseconds information?` - the expected result has zeros anyway.

Comment: `date --iso-8601=ns -d @1606982602.015489365`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Insert a comma:

```
date --iso-8601=ns -d @1606982602.015489365
```

Comment: Is this a save way to go? Do timestamps with nanosecond precision differ in length or is it safe to assume, that the length is always the same. I`m asking this, because i read out this timestamps from another source and i would need to separate all of the incoming timestamps at the ninth digit.

Comment: Surely "timestamp" represented as seconds since epoch will be "shorter" when the date is closed to epoch. I mean `date --iso-8601=ns -d @1.123456789`. I do not understand. Do you ask how to insert a digit between 10th and 9th character from the left? I would `a=1606982602015489365; sed 's/[0-9]\{9\}$/.&/' <<<"$a"` but I just like `sed`, any tool would be fine.